# How to hide some beamer slides if variable is set?

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I have a lecture that I sometimes give in a class and sometimes in a workshop. When giving the workshop, I don't want to show all the frames, just most of them.

I know I can hide some frames by doing:

```
\begin{frame}<presentation:0>
...
\end{frame}
```

I want to specify a variable at the beginning indicating that it is a workshop and have all the non-workshop frames hidden. Something like this (The syntax here isn't crucial):

```
% Frame only when giving a class
% This should be hidden when giving a workshop
\begin{frame}<presentation:class>
\end{frame}

% Frame when giving a class *and* a workshop
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: If you can rerun LsTeX, sure.  \newif\ifworkshop, \workshoptrue and \workshopfalse is one way.

Comment: I can rerun LaTeX, but I'm not sure how to utilize the variables as you have indicated.

Comment: OTOH, the overlay specification would be easier.  (Beamer is a world unto itself)  A full MWE would be useful here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\flag}{0}% 0 for class, 1 for workshop

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<presentation:\flag>
test 1
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
test 2
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```